# Usuários confiáveis precisam escrever o motivo da edição de perguntas ou respostas?

Tags: debate, edição, usuarios

**[Esta página da documentação do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)** descreve alguns privilégios do chamado "Usuário Confiável" (*trusted user*), privilégio este que é concedido ao alcançar 20 mil de reputação.

Salvo engano, acho que bem antes desses 20 mil o usuário já consegue fazer edições sem que seja preciso revisão, ou seja, aprovação através de votos (me corrijam se eu estiver enganado).

Mas focando nesse *status* de Usuário Confiável, quem possui tal *status* é dispensável escrever o motivo da edição ou é sempre bom escrever, independentemente da reputação? Pergunto isso porque algumas edições são tão óbvias que imagino ser dispensável escrever o motivo.

---

> A propósito, ao selecionar as tags para esta pergunta, tem muita coisa
>   duplicada, com e sem acento:
>
> [usuarios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usuarios) [usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usu%c3%a1rios) [interface-usuarios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface-usuarios)
>   [interface-usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface-usu%c3%a1rios)

Comment: Quanto às tags duplicadas, isso daí é algo para os moderadores resolverem, mas já é um outro assunto diferente.

Comment: É, só puxei um parênteses.

Comment: [Após os 2.000 pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) já é possível fazer edições sem revisão. Embora eu faça algumas edições sem revisão, por precaução sempre coloco as observações e os motivos do qual eu fiz.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Em qualquer edição é sempre bom escrever o motivo dela, independente da reputação. Isso serve para que outras pessoas entendam o que te levou a editar (ou até para você mesmo lembrar no futuro) sem precisar de comentários para isso, principalmente se a edição for algo grande.

No entanto, isso é uma recomendação, não é uma obrigação.

Comment: Hummmm... eu sempre achei que fosse uma obrigação rs... tanto que no início eu motivava até edições das minhas próprias respostas achando que se eu não o fizesse, poderia sofrer algum tipo de penalidade.

Comment: @dvd Penalidade só é passível em caso de abuso, mas isso é bem raro. Aqui no SOpt só vi casos de abuso em edições que eram vandalismos com a mensagem de edição contendo xingamentos, mas aí a edição inteira é abusiva. Em outros sites da SE, já vi caso de gente que escrevia um monte de besteiras nada a ver com nada e eu reclamei pros moderadores. Também já vi um que gerou algum ruído no meta do SOen com um usuário que fazia edições válidas, mas colocava mensagens da edição com conteúdo sexual. Esses tipos de abusos são casos para a moderação.

Comment: Pois eh, sempre aparece algum engraçadinho que quer zuar. Mas realmente, até por uma questão de organização, acho recomendável escrever o motivo da edição. E nem dá muito trabalho porque o navegador já salva o que já foi digitado antes, porque a maioria das vezes o motivo é o mesmo: "correções ortográficas no título", "formatação do código" etc.. são os que eu geralmente uso.

Comment: Eu escrevia no começo, depois parei porque a ferramenta meio que some com ela. Serve pra casos de dúvidas e conflitos, mas de forma geral quem deveria ver isto é a pessoa que não fez o texto ideal e vai ler o que ela precisa melhorar, mas a ferramenta deveria apresentar isto de forma ativa e não passiva, principalmente no começo. E ir mudando para o passivo conforme a pessoa for ganhando medalhas que indique que ele foi aprendendo. Tem muita coisa que é muito esforço pra pouco resultado.